# How to get user password expiry date information when PSO fine grained policy is in force for Windows OS using AdsGetObject MSDN API?

Tags: c++, c++11, windows-server-2012, msdn

Currently, we are using AdsGetObject MSDN API to get the password expiry information of user using https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/ad/example-code-for-searching-for-users example and it is working fine for Group Policy Object password expiry information.

But yesterday, we got the escalation, where this API is not honoring the password expiration enforced through password setting object policies.

Does anyone have idea is there any way where this API can honor PSO policies over Group Policies to get the password expiry data? Even `net user <username>` command also return the password expire date based on Group Policies not PSO policies.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this appears to work for me

```
swprintf(wszCandidateAccount, _countof(wszCandidateAccount), L"WinNT://%s/%s, user", wszDomainOrMachine, wszUserName);

if (FAILED(hr = ADsOpenObject(wszCandidateAccount, NULL, NULL, ADS_SECURE_AUTHENTICATION, IID_IADsUser, (void **)&pIADsUser)))
{
    ShowError("ADsOpenObject->Retrieving user object", hr);
    CoUninitialize();
    return 1;
}

DATE expDate;
hr = pIADsUser->get_PasswordExpirationDate(&expDate);
```